# Bash printf formating not working

Tags: bash, printf

For example, the `\c` format does not work.
I'm input `printf "ABC\ctest"` to bash console and result;

```
ABC\ctest
```

Considering the `\c` format's property, the expected output should be in the form of just `ABC`.

Nor did I find a proper source that detailed the use of the printf command on bash. Also, as in the above example, the properties on the man page specified for the printf command do not work correctly.

Please show me a source on bash that explains the printf command  in detail. Because I'm so confused right now.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: The man page that you are reading is probably for [POSIX printf](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) whereas the behavior you see in the terminal is likely your shell's builtin `printf` implementation. The former may be present on your system as `/usr/bin/printf` for example so see if `/usr/bin/printf "ABC\ctest"` gives the expected behavior.

Comment: @steeldriver The behavior he is expecting is not POSIX compliant. He may be on linux where a non-compliant `/usr/bin/printf` with a related non-compliant man page exists, that incorrectly mentions and implements '\c' for the format string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ```
> printf 'ABC\ctest'
> ```

You've hit upon one of the unspecified parts of the `printf` command, whose behaviour varies from implementation to implementation.  You're putting the `\c` in the wrong place.

If you read [the *Single Unix Specification*'s description of `printf`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) carefully, you will see that `\c` is not listed in the list of escape sequences that are defined for the format string (the first argument to the command).  Rather, it is defined as an *extra* escape sequence that is recognized when given *in an argument string* that is to be formatted *by the `%b` format specifier*.

In other words:

- `printf '%b\n' 'ABC\ctest'` has a well specified behaviour.  The `\c` causes everything remaining (including the newline in the format string) to be ignored.
- `printf '%s\n' 'ABC\ctest'` has a well specified behaviour.  The `\c` is not an escape sequence in the first place.
- `printf '\c'` does not have a well specified behaviour.  The *SUS* is simply silent upon what `\c` is, not listing it as an escape sequence but also not saying in its *File Format Notation* section that such a sequence is never an escape sequence.

How different shells behave in response to this non-conformant format string varies quite significantly.  Here are the Debian Almquist, Bourne Again, FreeBSD Almquist, Korn '93, and Z shells' reactions (with `%`s showing where no newlines have been emitted):

```
% dash -c "printf 'ABC\ctest\n'"
ABC\ctest
% bash -c "printf 'ABC\ctest\n'"
ABC\ctest
% sh -c "printf 'ABC\ctest\n'"
ABC%
% ksh93 -c "printf 'ABC\ctest\n'"
ABCest
% zsh -c "printf 'ABC\ctest\n'"
ABC%
%
```

The builds of the MirBSD Korn and PD Korn shells that I have do not have a `printf` built-in command.  The FreeBSD non-built-in `printf` does this:

```
% /usr/bin/printf 'ABC\ctest\n'
ABC%
%
```

Adding to the fun is that the doco for the various shells is sometimes highly misleading and even sometimes downright erroneous.  For examples:

- [The Z shell doco](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-printf) only recently started to give a correct description of what `\c` does, and lists it (via its doco for `echo`) as an escape sequence allowed in format strings.  (It was incorrect [until 2017](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/commit/1db0eea95ae3d09475a8746ed85fe764b7c89798), the doco neither agreeing with the *SUS* nor describing what the Z shell actually did.)
- The Korn '93 shell doco gives a description that is in line with the *SUS*, but it is not (as can be seen in the aforegiven) what it actually does when `\c` is in the format specifier.  It, too, documents `\c` as an escape sequence for the format string.  Its behaviour is clearly a bug.
- [The doco for the Bourne Again shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-printf) and [the doco for the Debian Almquist shell](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/dash/dash.1.en.html#printf) give a description of `\c` that matches the *SUS* and explicitly list it in relation to `%b` (in the case of the Bourne Again shell more clearly than it does now [up until 2016](https://github.com/gitGNU/gnu_bash/blob/30a978b7d808c067219c95be88c4979b6a7aa251/doc/bashref.texi#L4238)) and *not* in a general list of escape sequences for `printf` format specifiers.  These shells do not provide this as an extension to the standard.
- [The FreeBSD Almquist shell doco](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh) defers to the FreeBSD external `printf` command manual, whose description of `\c` is in line with the *SUS*.  It explicitly lists it as an escape sequence allowed in format strings, and its actual behaviour is as documented in the user manual.

The FreeBSD Almquist shell and (recent) Z shell are the only shells, here, that both document allowing `\c` as an escape sequence in format strings (an extension to what is defined by the standard) *and* actually behave as they are documented.

## Ironic further reading

- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/5132)

Comment: Thank you seperate your time for my question.

Comment: BTW: ksh93 converts `\ct` in a format string into the character `0x14` - looks like control-t. And thank you for mentioning that `printf` is as problematic as `echo` as a result of implementors that ignore POSIX.

Answer (score 5):

It is necessary to expand backslash escape sequences in the corresponding argument.
As stated in [here](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf.):

```
\c  Terminate output similarly to the \c escape used by echo -e. printf produces no additional output after coming across a \c escape in a %b argument.
```

```bsh
$ printf "%b\n" "ABC\chi"
ABC
```