# What is this POSIX echo \c?

Tags: posix, echo, gnu

While looking for the plain truth on `echo` I found this page:

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html

It's normally a HTML frame on this site https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ (where you can search for "echo").

This claims to be POSIX, but I see no `-n` and I see `\c` instead!

**What have I found?**

GracefulRestart [points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/565785/what-is-this-posix-echo-c#comment1052190_565785) that `/bin/echo` recognises `\c` but it doesn't do that by default: I must do `echo -e` for `\c` to be recognised.

Comment: On your system, run the command `type -a echo`.  Usually, you will have a shell built-in called `echo` provided by your shell in addition to `/usr/bin/echo` which would have the flags you are looking for.  The shell built-in usually supersedes the installed program.

Comment: not here, I have the gnu coreutils 8.3 echo as /bin/echo  it recognises `-n` and requires `-e` to regognise `\c`  `$ /bin/echo --version` `echo (GNU coreutils) 8.30` `Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
`

Comment: Does _"This claims to be POSIX, but..."_ imply that you believe that that is not the POSIX specification for `echo`? Since you are mentioning GNU: notes about POSIX compatibility can be found in `info coreutils echo`; they are not included in `man echo`.

Comment: I found a web site on the internet but wasn't sure if it was legit... info says `If the ‘POSIXLY_CORRECT’ environment variable is set,`... I think that answers my question.

Comment: If you want to write things to the screen in a portable manner, [use `printf` instead of `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).

Comment: Your question is confusing: What is "straight dope" and "frame", much of the question is off site. It also needs some grammar.

Comment: `POSIXLY_CORRECT` in some cases makes GNU software more POSIX compliant, but only in rare cases fully compliant. `bash` neither becomes fully POSIX compliant by this environment, nor by calling `set -o posix`. You need a special compile option. At runtime, the switch is hidden under `shopt`.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor "straight dope" is  "truth".    
"frame" as in HTML - because  I can't link to the whole page as I see it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have found IEEE 1003.1-2017, a.k.a. the *Single Unix Specification*, published by The Open Group.

For more, see "[What exactly is POSIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11983/5132)", "[Difference between POSIX, Single UNIX Specification, and Open Group Base Specifications?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14368/5132)", and all of their linked questions and answers.

The `-n` is there, in boldface no less so it is hard to miss.  And yes, `\c` is standard.

The variations in behaviour of `echo` are notorious.  You should not be surprised that `/bin/echo` is not the same as a shell built-in `echo`, and that one requires an `-e` where another does not.  It's not even *that* simple.

For a long explanation, see "[Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/5132)".

For the little-known variability of `printf`, ironically involving the very same `\c` escape sequence, see "[Bash printf formating not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/558636/5132)".

Comment: To make it easier to understand: `linux` and gnu tools are mostly POSIX compliant, but for a UNIX branding, you need to implement **all** XSI enhancements. This is where Linux is far from being standard compliant. `dash` e.g. does not implement support for multibyte characters.

Answer (score -2):

If you were on a POSIX certified platform with UNIX branding, `echo` did handle `\c` by default.

This applies to Solaris, AIX, HP-UX and Apple.

Apple even uses `bash` to support this echo behavior, but you need a specific compile option to make `bash` compliant by default. This compile option for `bash` is used for MacOS and for Solaris. So peole may be confused when they realise that `bash` behaves different on a POSIX certified platform,

Remember: `GNU` reads GNU is not UNIX.... many GNU tools are not POSIX compliant or not POSIX compliant by default. So be careful when you are not on a certified platform.

BTW: You may get the POSIX branding for small embedded platforms even when you do not support `echo \c`, but for a `UNIX` branding, you need to support **all** `XSI` extensions to POSIX. Linux does not support most of the `XSI` extensions. Many Linux distros e.g. use `dash` as the default shell and `dash` id definitely not compliant, e.g. because it does not support multi byte characters.