# Why does printf byte formatting fail when executed under `dash`?

Tags: bash, shell, printf, dash

The ASCII hex code for a zero is 0x30. Hence, you can print a zero by doing `printf '\x30'`, and it will print a zero.

If you put this into a shell script called myScript.sh, and then execute `./myScript.sh`, it will also print a zero.

But if you execute `sh -c printf '\x30'` or alternatively, `sh myScript.sh`, you will instead get the literal characters "\x30", rather than having it be interpreted as a single byte.

Why is that?

(Behavior has been observed on multiple machines, all of which I believe are running bash).

Comment: Somewhat related [Bash printf formating not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/558665/65304) . IIRC *octal* escapes should be portable - try `\060`

Comment: If you say `sh myScript.sh`, then you have explicitly told sh (i.e. dash) to execute the text of your script itself. The shebang (because it starts with `#`) is just a comment in that case. The `#!` is a "magic number" which is only actioned when the file containing it is executed via the execve() system call.

Answer (score 7):

The implementation of `printf` in some shells (`bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, at least; even in `sh` emulation mode) understands `\xHH` as the hexadecimal number `HH`. This is however an extension to [the standard `printf` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html).

What's required by the POSIX standard is that `printf` recognize `\0ddd`, where `ddd` is a zero, one, two, or three digit *octal* number.

The shell that stands in for `/bin/sh` on your system is most likely `dash` (or, less likely, `yash`), which understands octal (like all standard shells), but does not understand hexadecimal, when used with `printf`.

The hexadecimal number 30 is 60 in octal, so

```
$ sh -c 'printf "%b\n" "$1"' sh '\060'
0
```

Or, if you don't want to pass the octal number as an argument but instead want to use it as a static literal:

```
$ sh -c 'printf "\060\n"'
0
```

(Note the difference here to the `sh -c` statement in your question: the whole `printf` statement, including its arguments, are part of the string given as the option-argument to the `sh` utility's `-c` option.  I'm assuming what you have in your question is a simple typo.)

The reason your script managed to print a zero correctly is either because you had a `#!`-line in the script that pointed to the `bash` shell executable, or you had *no* such line at all and instead ran the script from an interactive `bash` shell.  The `bash` shell, when executing a shell script with no `#!` line, will use `bash` to run it (see [Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373223) for more about this detail).

When you run the script with an explicit interpreter, as in `sh myScript.sh`, the `#!` line, if there is one, will be ignored.

Comment: Note: [POSIX printf](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) recognizes the `\0ddd` form (with the `0`) only in arguments interpreted by the `b` specifier, not in the format string. In the format string, it recognizes the `\ddd` form (without the `0`). For example, these are equivalent: `/usr/bin/printf '%b' '\0060'`, `/usr/bin/printf '%b' '\060'`, `/usr/bin/printf '\060'`. But this is not: `/usr/bin/printf '\0060'`. A hex dump of the last one will show that it results in _two_ bytes: `0x06 0x30`.

Answer (score 1):

When I execute

```
$ sh -c printf '\x30'
```

I get

```
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
```

which already provides a precious hint that `printf` doesn't get the expected parameters. The solution is to make sure the command parameter is a single string, not multiple parameters, by enclosing it in quotes. And of course adding a newline for readability doesn't hurt:

```
$ sh -c "printf '\x30\n'"
0
```