# How to printf ascii characters with hex or dec inside /bin/sh -c '...'?

Tags: printf, dash

/bin/sh would be dash
what is the correct syntax for printf to display certain ascii character using hex or dex code in dash?
let's say i want to printf a dollar sign ($). which hex or dec code should be used and how?

Comment: Related: [Why does printf byte formatting fail when executed under `dash`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/627036/why-does-printf-byte-formatting-fail-when-executed-under-dash)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to go from the character code to the character itself, you include the character code in the `printf` format string, escaped with a backslash, *in octal*.

E.g. `printf "\044\n"` prints `$` (and a newline).

In Bash and other shells, you could use hex, `\x24`, but that's not standard and doesn't work in Dash.

You could nest another `printf` in a command substitution to convert from hex or decimal to octal, though. Both of these would print `$` (and a newline):

```
printf "\\$(printf %o 36)\n"
printf "\\$(printf %o 0x24)\n"
```

Comment: Nice.printf "\044\n" works well.

Comment: Note that `$` is only octal 44, hex 24 when expressed in the ASCII charset (and all its supersets such as iso8859-15, gb18030 or UTF-8). `printf '\44\n'` will print a `$` on a large majority of POSIX systems, but certainly not all of them, and POSIX for example does not guarantee that it does. `printf '\u0024'` wherever supported should print a `$` though as that's the U+0024 character, even where its encoding is not the 0x44 byte. So would `printf '\44' | iconv -f ASCII` (more portable).